# How to get Mono command line parameters?

Tags: c#, mono

I run my application with command line like this:

```
path-to-mono/mono --debug myapp.exe
```

1. Is there any way to determine the presence of the --debug parameter (or others, if I use them)?
2. Can I get the path to mono executable with which I started the app? (I know some methods to determine the installation path, but this is not that I need.)

Comment: Have you tried `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`? I don't know how it behaves in Mono (haven't tried it), but I suspect it includes the mono executable and its arguments

Comment: I tried it and it ignores everything before myapp.exe in command line. Maybe to show the same functionality under Mono and without it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use the Mono embedding API, you cannot do this (you're asking how to access metadata that only the runtime knows).

Comment: I understand this. And I am asking how to access this API, and is this API exists?

Comment: for the case of the --debug flag, the setting is stored in a C static variable, so it's not public I'm afraid: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/26d0b81c266f87df259ccb297bc22d60768e2e72/mono/mini/driver.c , you may want to propose a PR? I did recently expose API to get the --server flag: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/26d0b81c266f87df259ccb297bc22d60768e2e72